# Closed ball not a manifold.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

My book on differential geometry claims that a closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$ can never be a differentiable manifold because of the boundary points. The book doesn't really give an explanation for why this is true. Could someone provide more details please? thanks

Comment: I also wanted to rigorously check out this detail but I am a little bit disappointed by the answers. We want to proove that there exists no homeomorphism between $U\cap \overline{B}_n$ ($U$ an open neighborhood of a boundary point of the closed n-dimensional ball $B_n$) and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What I consider a real "proof" can be found in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739962/half-space-is-not-homeomorphic-to-euclidean-space)

Answer (score 10):

The points on the boundary only have neighborhoods homeomorphic to an open ball in
$$\Bbb R^n_+ = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Bbb R^n : x_1 \geq 0\}$$
centered on the boundary. Such a set is not open in all of $\Bbb R^n$.

For example, consider the closed unit ball $[-1, 1]$ in $\Bbb R$. Then any open neighborhood of $1$ has a connected component of the form $(1 - \varepsilon, 1]$, which is not open in $\Bbb R$. But the definition of an $n$-manifold requires that each point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an *open* set in $\Bbb R^n$; therefore $[-1,1]$ cannot be a manifold in the usual sense.

The closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is an example of a **manifold with boundary**.

Comment: Thank you for the nice response, the one dimensional example was very illuminating.

Comment: Just because the neighborhood is homeomorphic to something that is not open in the ambient space doesn't _a priori_ mean it can't also be homeomorphic to something else that _is_.

Answer (score 1):

a manifold is differentiable, if there exist an atlas for it. the atlas contains compatible charts (We call the pair $(U,f : U →R^n)$ a chart, $U$ a coordinate
neighborhood or a coordinate open set, and $f$ a coordinate map or a coordinate
system on U. f is a homeomorphism onto an open
subset of $R^n$)

for boundary points we cannot define a chart (like above definition) because neighborhoods of these points are not homeomorphic to an open
subset of $R^n$.